# Azure best practice

Tags: azure, security, software-design

What is the best practice with windows Azure key vault. Is it a good practice to extract keys  within the application every time we make use of it or it is good to set them in the OS environment variable.

Comment: Getting them from a secure store and then storing them in an environment variable everyone can read wouldn't make it good practice imho.

Comment: On linux server, I would create user for the app. I would also store the keys in the user's profile. This is just to save on frequently acessing the vault

Comment: Define frequently. If it is retrieved multiple times in the same instance I would prefer an inmemory cache.

Comment: Frequently, could be multiple times, as needed. The in memory cache is the equivalent to the environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what key. You should not be extracting master key, but the associated data keys to encrypt and decrypt.

Answer (score 0):

There is no hard-fast rule here but you should consider the rotation of keys.  If you need the keys to be rotated often you should consider pulling from Key Vault every time.

There are other times in makes more sense to pull once and cache locally.  This could include your network latency being an issue so it's more cost-effective to pull once then cache.  In this scenario, you will need some mechanism in place to force a new pull if/when the key is rotated.